# finding divisors of N using a list comprehension

Tags: python

I have started to write some Python code. What I have is:

```
from math import *
def ex(N):        
    l = []
    sum = 0
    N = abs(int(N));
    for n in range(1,N):
        if N % n == 0:
            l.append(n)
            sum += n
    l.append(N) 
    print '  of '+str(N),l
    print 'SUM', (sum+N)
```

I don't know if this is good or bad, but it is what I have tried :)

Is it possible to replicate the behavior of my code with list comprehension? If so, how?

Comment: Well, do you know what list comprehensions are and did you bother to try learning them on your own?

Comment: yes,I know alitle but not too much.:)

Comment: What is the *intent* of your code? Especially the line `if N % n == 0`.

Comment: You should also read chapters 3 and 4 of http://diveintopython.org/

Comment: 20 => 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20

Comment: before you ask if N % n == 0 now you give me read docs.

Comment: FYI, sum is a Python built in function, thus it's considered unwise for use as a variable name .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simply (this actually uses a generator expression rather than a list comprehension, if you don't need to keep the results).

```
def ex(N):
    N = abs(int(N))
    print 'SUM', sum(n for n in xrange(1, N + 1) if N % n == 0)
```

If you care about the list, then instead:

```
def ex2(N):
    N = abs(int(N))
    l = [n for n in xrange(1, N + 1) if N % n == 0]
    print '  of '+str(N),l
    print 'SUM', sum(l)
```

You might find the [Dive Into Python 3](http://diveintopython3.org/comprehensions.html#listcomprehension) explanation of list comprehensions useful, or if you've got some free hours, try watching an [introductory Python tutorial](http://us.pycon.org/2010/tutorials/williams_python101/).

Comment: Nicholas Riley you are give me the right answer easy to understand ,and good docs you shared. thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
l = [n for n in range(1,N+1) if N % n == 0]
total = sum(l)
```

Comment: You are forgetting to add the N in the end of the list. He always appends it.

Comment: @SanSS: Whoops, fixed. (N%N is always 0)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with list-comprehension:

```
def ex(N):
    N = abs(int(N))
    l = [n for n in range(1, N + 1) if N % n == 0]
    print '  of '+str(N),l
    print sum(l)
```

You will keep the n for each n in the range from 1 to N(inclusive) if the condition(N % n == 0) is true. You will keep the list in l and then the function sum calculates the sum of the list.

Whether it is good or bad using list comprehension is up to you, but it is usually used as it is efficient and compact. And if you don't need a list because you just need to use the values one after the other and only one time `generators` are recommended because they don't use memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to replace:

```
for n in range(1,N):
        if N % n == 0:
            l.append(n)
```

with:

```
[l.append(n) for n in range(1,N) if N % n == 0]
```

Whether it is good or bad, in this case, I'm not sure.  I like to use them when I can, but for more complex cases sometimes I opt for the `for` loop for readability.

**Edit:** Sorry, maybe I should have given a complete example.

```
def ex(N):    
    l = []
    N = abs(int(N));
    [l.append(n) for n in range(1,N) if N % n == 0]
    l.append(N)
    print l
    print sum(l)
```

Comment: This list comprehension will result in a `NameError` or in a list of `None` references.

Comment: l = [n for n in range(1,N) if N % n == 0] I think